# Getting error in autoscaling with keda in aws eks cluster

Tags: amazon-eks, autoscaling, keda

I am trying to use KEDA to perform autoscaling of different agent pods according to a metric value exposed by an API; however, auto-scaling doesn't work.

Please see the below yaml file.

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: scaledobject
  namespace: keda
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: gas-agent-deployment
  pollingInterval: 10    # Interval for polling
  cooldownPeriod: 10
  idleReplicaCount: 0   # When idle, scale-in to 0 pods
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 40
  triggers:
    - type: metrics-api
      metadata:
        targetValue: "1"
        activationTargetValue: "1"
        url: "http://ip:port/metric"
        valueLocation: 'data.gas_agent'
```

1. Verified that the API server serving the metric is working and returning the correct json response (e.g. `{'data': {'gas_agent': '1'}}`)
2. When I deployed the `ScaledObject`, its not auto-scaling.
3. `keda_operator` is logging the following below error messages:

```
2023-07-28T06:24:57Z    ERROR   scale_handler   error getting scale decision    {"scaledObject.Namespace": "keda", "scaledObject.Name": "scaledobject", "scaler": "metricsAPIScaler", "error": "error requesting metrics endpoint: Get \"http://10.100.214.179:3000/metric\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"}
```